# How do I Add Integration Services to existing SQL Server 2012 Install that has no internet access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, installation

Did a bunch of hunting, but I have a SQL 2012 Developer instance that's on an isolated network (no internet access, except for VPN to it). At install time we didn't install integration services, and my developer needs to deploy/configure SSIS packages.

I tried a few things, and got stuck. Part of the issue is that we appear to need some flavor of VS, and I'd assumed that I already had it per below.

[image]

Would appreciate a step by step.. keeping in mind that whatever I put on the machine can't be dependent on getting files from the internet.

Comment: For SSIS you can download and use SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools)

Comment: Understood; however, is that enough, or does one need some flavor of Visual Studio installed? and also, where can I find an offline SSDT installer (remember, we have no internet access). What I tried to install, was trying to download pieces from MS.

Comment: Yes, SSDT installs a minimal Visual Studio framework

Comment: @McNets can you point me to where I can find offline SSDT installer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an administrative install point:
`SSDTSetup.exe /layout <destination>` 
then copy the files to your isolated instance.
Check out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2014/07/23/creating-an-administrative-install-of-ssdt-update-for-visual-studio-2013/ for details.